# Is there any better way to access the value of each step in the StepMenu?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have made this code to access each step of the stepmenu and change its number value for a char 'check'.

My question is if there is a better way to do it.

```
valueChanged() {
    this.value.emit(this.activeIndex);
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-steps-number") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
    for (var _i = this.activeIndex-1; _i > -1; _i--) {
      x[_i].innerHTML = "✔";
      x[_i].style.backgroundColor = "#0081c2";
    }
    for (var _i = this.activeIndex+1; _i<this.items.length; _i++){
      let str = (_i+1).toString() 
      x[_i].innerHTML = str;
      x[_i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    }
    x[this.activeIndex].innerHTML = (this.activeIndex+1).toString();
    x[this.activeIndex].style.backgroundColor = "#0081c2";
  }
```

Comment: Just as a tip. You should start using let and const and stop using vars :)

Comment: Sure you can use an "Angular style":ngClass, *ngFor,interpolation {{}}... https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: Thanks, you! ;)!